# How to call a make a function call first to happen

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two functions fun1() and fun2() in fun1 ,fun2 is called which returns status on which basis rest of the code works in fun1 but before fun2 return fun1 rest of the code is been executed ! Because node js is a Unblocked procedural code based one ! How to handle my case ?

```
    async function isDuplicateUser(emailId)
{
  var condition=false;
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "32577488",
    database:"mydb"
  });
  var sql='SELECT count(*) AS namesCount FROM UserDetails WHERE emailId ="'+emailId+'";';
  con.connect(function(err) {
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err){
        throw err;
        return ;
      }
      if(result[0].namesCount>=1)
      {
        condition=true;
        console.log("Upper check :"+condition);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log("Lower check :"+condition);
  return condition;
}
```

In logger I am seeing LowerCheck at first and then Upper check logger please help me !

Comment: This is not clear at all, post the code that you're struggling with, it sounds like the issue isn't Node at all, but asynchronicity ?

Comment: Please see now !

Comment: I see, you're using async functions, and need to learn how to work with those, see the duplicate for a good explanation on how it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Please see the question now !

Comment: It's still a duplicate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with:

1. Callbacks (only pure ES5 solution)
2. Promises (my solution below)
3. Async functions (also uses Promises)

Because Promises are the most intuitive for me I wrote working solution in ES6 and with Promises:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connectionConfig = {
  host:"localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database:"mydb"
}

/** Firstly, connect with DB; so you will be able to share connection */
const conn = mysql.createConnection(connectionConfig);
conn.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  /** After then create server */
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.get('/',(req,res) => { res.send(`hello express`) });
  app.get('/about',(req,res) => { res.send(`Thank you!`) });

  app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

    isDuplicateUser(req.body.email)
      .then((userPresent) => {

        if(userPresent) {
          console.log(`User Already present`);
          res.status(409).json({message: `User already present`});
        } else {
          const query = `INSERT INTO UserDetails (email, password, name) VALUES ('${req.body.email}', '${req.body.password}','${req.body.name}')`;
          conn.query(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(`1 record inserted`);
            res.status(200).json({message: `1 record inserted`});
          });
        }

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`An unexpected error occurred`);
        res.status(500).json({message: `An unexpected error occurred`});
      });

  });

  app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/') );

  function isDuplicateUser(email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const query = `SELECT count(*) AS namesCount FROM UserDetails WHERE email='${email}';`;
      conn.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(result[0].namesCount > 0 ? true : false);
      });
    })
  }

});
```

Please, notice that I renamed names of columns in DB.

I hope, this example will help you understand how to work with async code.

Comment: Thank you so much ! But May I know why app.post or app.get is in con.connect !

Comment: Technically, in this case, you can move `app.get` before `conn.connect`. However, to prepare the response `app.post` uses `conn` so it needs to be inside `conn.connect`. In general, it is good practice to run server after setting a connection with a database. 

Indeed whole this code should be separated into minimum three files: `db.js` (to set and handle connection), `server.js` (to handle routes), `index.js` (to connect it all together). But there is not enough space here to explain how to do it ;/

Comment: Making it this way helps you prevent from displaying errors on front-end when the connection was not set yet.